# How to terminate Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I know there is a lot of questions about this. I tried them but can't get any result.

I'm creating a thread at first run, when I try to close the form, form closing but application (thread) is still running.

I don't care what will happen to thread. I just want whole application to close when user click to X button. I tried `thread_name.Abort();` but nothing happens.

Comment: How did you create the thread?

Comment: Is it a pure CLR app or is it interoperating with unmanaged code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the absence of code, a full answer is tricky.

I suspect the easiest solution might be to set the Thread's [IsBackground](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) property to true.

From the docs:

> A thread is either a background thread or a foreground thread. Background threads are identical to foreground threads, except that background threads do not prevent a process from terminating

Answer (score 2):

Try setting [Thread.IsBackground](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) to `true` when you create the thread.

Background threads do not stop the process from terminating if they are running.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare your thread as a foreground-thread, the application won't stop, because the thread is still alive, even though you clicked 'X'. You need to set it as a background-thread.

```
Thread.IsBackground = true;
```

Read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you asked I know, but the Task Parallel Library in .NET 4.0 supports cancellation in a fairly sensible way. It may or may not be viable in your situation but more detail can be had here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.100).aspx